# Single PHP File I need to Run as CGI

Tags: php, perl, apache, .htaccess

I have a legacy program that I need to run with the extension of .cgi (search.cgi), but I have re-written this code using PHP.

How do I tell Apache to reference search.cgi but make it run search.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the url rewriting mod of apache.
Somthing like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/search.cgi$ /search.php [QSA]
```

You can change search.cgi by ixsearch.cgi
Or more general

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9_\-]+)\.cgi$ /$1.php [NC, QSA]
```

That will rewrite any url yourdomain.com/{some_scriptname}.cgi in yourdomain.com/{some_scriptname}.php (and rewriting the request GET parameter thanks to QSA clause)
the script name can contain any letter between a and z or numer or char like - or _ (ex tomato-juice). Plus it is case insensitive (thanks to NC clause)

Comment: Close but still not working, I am using http://taildb.com/ixsearch.php?F=B&TN=N911DE and need it to render the same thing via http://taildb.com/ixsearch.cgi?F=B&TN=N911DE

Answer (score 1):

Use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to rewrite requests for search.cgi to search.php.

Answer (score 0):

Just write it as a regular CGI like you've done but make it run using the command line version of PHP so that it runs like a regular CGI.

Comment: This will work, but generally it's better to run PHP scripts via mod_php if possible.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams no it's not. mod_php is horrible and a bad idea, popularity notwithstanding. Sane admins run PHP via FastCGI.

Comment: @hobbs: Sane admins don't run PHP at all unless they're forced to.

Comment: I work for an organisation that has a PHP based website and it's currently deployed as a FastCGI. I don't directly work on that project but I've been told by the ops people that they explicitly chose to run it in this fashion instead of using `mod_php`. Ignacio, why do you recommend `mod_php`?